# How can I set the vnet number for my KVM VM?

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I need to ba able to sniff the vnetX interface that is created for a KVM VM when it starts. The problem is, the X in vnetX is automatically incremented from 0 with each VM. I've read somewhere that this number can be configured. How can I set it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be easier to simply find out the currently used vnetX number from the qemu-kvm cmdline, and use that.

Having said that, it is possible to set the "X" if you run VMs using the qemu-kvm command line, instead of the libvirt wrappers.

I'd opt for the first option